# how do i re-arrange image document description to actual values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to derive accuracy of the face detection model for which i have actual and predicted values as labels (1,0) 1 being true is face found and 0 being false for not found. actual and predicted document descriptions are randomly distributed .. there are totally 1700 images so its tedious to make manual alterations.

Is there anyway I can do a reference check with both actual and predicted values so that I can bring back predicted values matching actual ones

> Blockquote
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eduOF.png)

Comment: Always try to put sample data and desired output with what you have tried already. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Harun24HR i tried to use sort function by taking sort by column as actual value column ..but could not imitate the same order in which actual columns are placed into predicted columns ... also face detection fields should not be altered .. right now i am doing manual comparison for accuracy derivation